# docker all files belong to root

Tags: docker

I recently started using docker on Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem I encounter is that everytime I run any script inside docker, all new files (which docker creates) have the root:root permissions.

I have read that this is a common issue, but I cannot find a proper solution for this problem (ideally the files created by docker would have my 'local machine' user's permissions.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or should I run chown / chmod after each docker creates new files?

Comment: https://medium.com/redbubble/running-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root-user-7d2e00f8ee15

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `--user` flag. If you know your UID and UID you can use it directly:

```
docker run --user 1000:1001 image
```

Or you can let your shell to evaluate it:

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) image
```

Comment: that sounds ok, but (note that I am a total beginner) my company uses "docker-compose up" to run docker (is that a difference?), then I know I should make my mind, but I am not sure if I should run "services" (e.g. apache) as myself, those should probably run as root. Also there is no "my current user" inside the docker, would not that be a problem? I would be most happy if it was like now without docker = services run as root, but when I run e.g. "php my-script", it creates files with my current user's permissions